# Vim: How to apply external command only to lines matching pattern

Tags: regex, vim

Two of my favorite Vim features are the ability to apply standard operators to lines matching a regex, and the ability to filter a selection or range of lines through an external command. But can these two ideas be combined?

For example, I have a text file that I use as a lab notebook, with notes from different dates separated by a line of dashes. I can do something like delete all the dash-lines with something like `:% g/^-/d`. But let's say I wanted to resize all the actual text lines, without touching those dash lines.

For a single paragraph, this would be something like `{!}fmt`. But how can this be applied to *all* the non-dash paragraphs? When I try what seems the logical thing, and just chain these two together with `:% v/^-/!fmt`, that doesn't work. (In fact, it seems to crash Vim...)

Is there a way to connect these two ideas, and only pass lines (not) matching a pattern into an external command like `fmt`?

Comment: I don't think Vim is crashing, I find it much more likely that the result of fmt is producing more lines, and thus ends up recursing endlessly (and building a huge file)

Comment: Don't use the `%` range with `:g` and `:v`, they apply to the whole buffer by default anyway.

Comment: @Sarah You're right that Vim isn't crashing here, but the reason is that the asker used `:!fmt` without a range. Without a range `:!fmt` reads from standard input. There's no crash, *fmt* is just waiting for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider how the `:global` command works.

`:global` (and `:v`) make two passes through the buffer,

- first marking each line that matches,
- then executing the given command on the marked lines.

Thus if you can come up with a command – be it an Ex command or a command-line tool – and an associated range that can be applied to each matching line (and range), you have a winner.

For example, assuming that your text is soft-wrapped and your paragraphs are simply lines that *don't* begin with minus, here's how to reformat the paragraphs:

```
:v/^-/.!fmt -72
```

Here we used the range `.` "current line" and thus filtered every matching line through *fmt*. More complicated ranges work, too. For instance, if your text were hard-wrapped and paragraphs were defined as "from a line beginning with minus, up until the next blank line" you could instead use this:

```
:g/^-/.,'}!fmt -72
```

Help topics:

- [`:h multi-repeat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#multi-repeat)
- [`:h :range!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3arange!)
- [`:h :range`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3arange)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it may be applying the command to the lines matching the pattern 'not containing only dashes'

The solution I would try the is something like (not tested):

```
:g/\v^(-+)@!/normal V!fmt
```

***EDIT*** I was doing some experiments and I think a recurvie macro should work for you

first of all set nowrapscan:

```
set nowrapscan
```

To prevent the recursive macro executing more than you want.

Then you make a search:

```
/\v^(-+)@!
```

Test if pressing `n` and `p` works with your pattern and tune it up if needed

After that, start recording the macro

```
qqn:.!awk '{print $2}'^M$
```

In this case I use awk as an example `.!` means filter current line with an external program
Then to make the macro recursive just append the string `'@q'` to the register `@q`

```
let @q .= '@q'
```

And move to the beggining of the buffer to apply the recursive macro and make the modifications:

```
gg@q
```

Then you are done. Hope this helps